# Coroutine only works the first time

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I assume that there is something fundamental about coroutines that I don't understand because I cannot get my head around why this is happening.

I have this coroutine that works perfectly as intended the first time but completely fails the second time I try to use it.

```
public IEnumerator CharacterDialogue()
{
    inDialogue = true;
    playerController.enabled = false;
    mouselook.enabled = false;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
    Cursor.visible = true;
    dialogueMenu.SetActive(true);

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    for (int i = 0; i < dialogueStrings.Length; i++)
    {
        while (!Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        dialogueText.text = dialogueStrings[i];
    }

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    while (!Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    QuestManager.Instance.SpawnDouxland();
    inDialogue = false;
    playerController.enabled = true;
    mouselook.enabled = true;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
    dialogueMenu.SetActive(false);
}
```

It is pretty straightforward: I disable the controls of my player and make the dialogue window pop. I then wait for the input of the player between each string of text so that he may read at his own pace. Once he's done reading I reactivate the controls and close the dialogue window.

This code works exactly like I want the first time but the second time it just goes through the for loop without waiting for the input.

What am I doing wrong here and why does it work the first time?

Edit:

Comments pointed out that the issue must be in the way I call the coroutine. This now makes sense to me as I use the same key (e) to call the coroutine. So maybe it reads the key as pressed and runs through the for loop. Bu why would it only do so the second time?

Here's the snippet of code where I call my coroutine:

```
        if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Character"))
        {
            raycastedObj = hit.collider.gameObject;
            CrosshairActive();
            interactionManager.InteractiveFeedbackTextCall("CharacterQuest");
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
            {
                Debug.Log("I have interacted with: " + hit.collider.gameObject.name + ".");
                StartCoroutine(canvasAnimManager.CharacterDialogue());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Coroutines will not endlessly loop. The code itself looks fine, it might have to do with how or where you are calling it a second time. I would have to say that putting Input detection in a non Update function though can get wonky. I would instead put the Input in Update then have a bool that changes when your key is pressed. Then inside of the IEnumerator, instead of while(!Input) do while(!keyNotHeldDown) once you set up the bool.

Comment: @TEEBQNE actually I see no problem in checking the Input in a Coroutine. In my eyes this is way cleaner than having to store the value in a class field and poll check it from there ... But yes, OP please show us how exactly you call this routine

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for the answers and pointing out that the issue is probably not inside the coroutine itself! I updated the question with the code snippet in which I call the coroutine.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some comments I figured out what the issue was.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
        {
            Debug.Log("I have interacted with: " + hit.collider.gameObject.name + ".");
            StartCoroutine(canvasAnimManager.CharacterDialogue());
        }
```

I thought the idea of GetKeyDown was that it was triggered only once... there must be something I'm not getting. Anyways the issue was that this was called multiple times and it make the coroutine go through the loop even after I was finished with my dialogue.

I just added a little bool check to fix the issue:

```
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("e") && !canvasAnimManager.inDialogue)
            {
                Debug.Log("I have interacted with: " + hit.collider.gameObject.name + ".");
                StartCoroutine(canvasAnimManager.FoukiDialogue());
            }
```

Cheers and thanks for the help!